# Linear line with variable points

Tags: linear-algebra

**Given the line $y = 2x + 1$ and point $A(10,-1)$**

*(a)* Show the point $T(t,2t+1)$ lies on the line $y = 2x +1$ for all values

How do I show this mathematically? I know logically $t = x$ and$ y = 2t+1$

$$2t+1 (y) = 2(t) +1 \implies 2t+1 = 2t+1$$ (Is this proving it? By substituting in the points and finding that they equal one another? is it that simple?

*(b)* What is the distance AT in terms of t?

Distance formula: $\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$

So would I simply plug in the values given point A and the changing point?

$\sqrt{(t-10)^2+((2t+1)-(-1))^2}$ => $\sqrt{5t^2-12t+104}$ ?

*(c)* For what value(s) of $t$ is the distance $AT$ smallest? Explain.

I'm not to sure what to do here.

Comment: (a) and (b) look good  (c) - the minimum distance will occur at the vertex of the parabola $5t^2-12t+104$

Comment: @WW1 Could you explain why? I graphed it and can visually see why this is, but can't quite explain it using terms.

Comment: because $\sqrt x$ is an increasing function the minimum of $\sqrt{ f(x) } $ must occur at the minimum of $f(x)$

Comment: @WW1 Oh alright. Thanks!